# How to display a particular menu items as second position in menu item order using wp_nav_menu_args?

Tags: wordpress

I have used the code below to add menu items in the nav menu

```
'add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_users_link', 10, 2 );
 function add_users_link( $items, $args ) {
      if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
       $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('/users') .'">Cadastro</a></li>';
     }
     elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {
        $items .= '<li><a href="'. site_url('wp-login.php') .'">Log In</a></li>';
      }
   return $items;
 }
```

I need to display the above items to the second position in the above code.
I have used sort_column and menu_order, but it not working

Anyone helps. THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways to do it:

#### With PHP

You can split your menu in two distinct menu then:

```
<?php
$args1 = array( 'menu' => 'header_menu_1' );
$args2 = array( 'menu' => 'header_menu_2' );
wp_nav_menu($args1);
?>

Your custom content here

<?php
wp_nav_menu($args2);
?>
```

#### With jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').eq(2).after('Your html content here');
});
```

#### With Css

You can change order of items with css and display: flex property
[See Flex order documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)